# Get specific href values or link from email which is parsed as html in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-email, exchangewebservices, html-agility-pack

I am processing emails in my C# service. I need to extract certain links present in the same to add to DB. I am using HtmlagilityPack. The div and p tags turn out interchangeable in the parsed email. I have to extract the links present below the tags 'Scheduler Link', 'Data Path' and 'Link' from the email. After cleaning it up, a sample data is as follows :

```
<html>
 <body>
   ......//contains some other tags which i dont need, may include hrefs but 
         //i dont need them 
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;">Scheduler link :</div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div style="margin:0;"><a href="https://something.com/requests/26428"> 
   https://something.com/requests/26428</a>
   </div>
   <div style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;">Data path :</div>
   <div align="left" style="text-align:justify;margin:0;"><a  
   href="file:///\\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\jui\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui"> 
   \\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\jui\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui</a>
   </div>
   <div align="left" style="text-align:justify;margin:0;"><a  
   href="file:///\\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui"> 
   \\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui</a>
   </div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;">Link :</div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;"><a 
   href="https://Thisisanotherlink.abcdef/sites/this/498592/rkjfb/3874y">
   This is some text</a></div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0 0 5pt 0;">This is another text</div>

   ......//contains some other tags which i dont need 
 </body>
</html>
```

I am looking for the div tag of 'Scheduler Link', 'Data Path' and 'Link' using regular expressions as follows :

```
HtmlNode schedulerLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + Regex.Match(body, _keyValuePairs["scheduler"]).Value.ToString() + "')]]");
HtmlNode dataPath = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + Regex.Match(body, _keyValuePairs["datapath"]).Value.ToString() + "')]]");
HtmlNode link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + Regex.Match(body, _keyValuePairs["link"]).Value.ToString() + "')]]");
```

The div tags are returning me the respective nodes. The number of links present against the three in each email varies and so does the order of the tags. I need to capture the links against each in a list. I am using the following code :

```
 foreach (HtmlNode link in schedulerLink.Descendants())
        {
        string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);     

            if (!(link.InnerText.Contains("\r\n")))
            {
                if (link.InnerText.Contains("/"))
                {
                    schedulersList.Add(link.InnerText.Trim());
                }
            }
        }
```

The descendants sometimes is not returning the correct number of nodes. Also how do i get the specific links against the 3 tags in 3 different lists since descendants usually return all the nodes present below.

Comment: Is there a way to identify individual by HREF only ?

Comment: Can you check my updated answer and see if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned different hrefs in your question,

one way of doing it is by following:

```
   var html = @"<html> <body> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'></div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'></div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'>Scheduler link :</div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'></div> <div style='margin:0;'><a href='https://something.com/requests/26428'> https://something.com/requests/26428</a> </div> <div style='margin:0;'></div> <div style='margin:0;'></div> <div style='margin:0;'></div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'>Data path :</div> <div align='left' style='text-align:justify;margin:0;'><a href='file:///\\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\jui\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui'> \\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\jui\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui</a> </div> <div align='left' style='text-align:justify;margin:0;'><a href='file:///\\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui'> \\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui</a> </div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'></div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'>Link :</div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0;'><a href='https://Thisisanotherlink.abcdef/sites/this/498592/rkjfb/3874y'> This is some text</a></div> <div align='justify' style='margin:0 0 5pt 0;'>This is another text</div> </body></html>";
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);

        var schedulerNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, \"something\")]");
        var dataPathNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, \"mycompany\")]");
        var linkNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, \"Thisisanotherlink\")]");

        foreach (var item in schedulerNodes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
            Debug.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
        }
        foreach (var item in dataPathNodes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
            Debug.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
        }
        foreach (var item in linkNodes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
            Debug.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
        }
```

Hope that helps !!

EDIT ::

```
    var result = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div//text()[normalize-space()] | //a");
// select all textnodes and a tags
            string sch = "Scheduler link :";
            string dataLink = "Data path :";
            string linkpath = "Link :";
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                if (item.InnerText.Trim().Contains(sch))
                {
                        var processResult = result.SkipWhile(x => !x.InnerText.Trim().Equals(sch)).Skip(1);
// skip the result till we reache to Scheduler.
                        Debug.WriteLine("====================Scheduler link=========================");
                        foreach (var subitem in processResult)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(subitem.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
// if href then add to list TODO
                            if (subitem.InnerText.Contains(dataLink)) // break when data link appears.
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (item.InnerText.Trim().Contains(dataLink))
                    {
                        var processResult = result.SkipWhile(x => !x.InnerText.Trim().Equals(dataLink)).Skip(1);
                        Debug.WriteLine("====================Data link=========================");

                        foreach (var subitem in processResult)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(subitem.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
                            if (subitem.InnerText.Contains(dataLink))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (item.InnerText.Trim().Contains("Link :"))
                    {
                        var processResult = result.SkipWhile(x => !x.InnerText.Trim().Equals(linkpath)).Skip(1);
                        Debug.WriteLine("====================Link=========================");
                        foreach (var subitem in processResult)
                        {
                            var hrefValue = subitem.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
                            Debug.WriteLine(hrefValue);
                            if (subitem.InnerText.Contains(dataLink))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have mentioned logic in code commments.

Hope that helps

Comment: The links are not consistent. Say for ex. you can receive https://sample.com, https://anotherexample.com, https://someothersite.com etc..I need the links present below the tags 'Scheduler Link', 'Data Path', 'Link', no matter what kind of links they are (web link or file path) or how many and in three different lists - schedulerLinkList, dataPathList, linkList.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to capture the content of the first href-attribute after a specific string like `scheduler link`. I don't know about the HtmlagilityPack, but my approach would be to just search the email body with a regex like this:

```
Scheduler link(?:\s|\S)*?href="([^"]+)
```

This regex should capture the content of the first href-attribute after every occurence of "Scheduler link" in the mail.

You can try it here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eoBXRh/2)

To find the other types of links just replace the `Scheduler link` part with the respective string.

I hope this is helpful.

Additional info about the regex:

- `Scheduler link` matches the string literally
- `(?:\s|\S)*?href="` non-capturing group that matches any character until the first occurence of the literal string `href="`
- `([^"]+)` captures everything despite the `"` character

Comment: The regex you shared is capturing all that comes after 'SchedulerLink' till the end of href without '"' like - Scheduler link :</div>
   <div align="justify" style="margin:0;"></div>
   <div style="margin:0;"><a href="https://something.com/requests/26428">. I need just - https://something.com/requests/26428. Moreover for Data Path there are two links and need those 2 as well - file:///\\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\jui\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui,file:///\\mycompany.com\ABC\OPQ1234\tui245.5t_2rtfg_tyui

Comment: The regex should just capture the `something.com/request/26428` part as a group, like it does in the regex101 example I provided. What implementation are you using, where it's not working for you? Regarding the Data Path: are there always exactly two links that need to be captured or is that number varying?